# Is there an analytical function with this shape?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I have drawn a shape [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRYKp.png) that I am trying to find an analytical form for.

It approximates a straight line $f(x) = bx$ and then converges to a constant value $c$, without ever exceeding $c$.

Are there any analytical forms for this behavior?

Comment: Tip: Crop the image (in MS Paint or some equivalent) so that only the relevant parts are included. Makes it easier to load, for example on mobile devices. As for the shape: Try stretching, rotating and translating the hyperbola $x^{2}-y^{2}=1,$ or, if you want overkill (probably not what you're looking for), then look into Bézier curves.

Comment: $c(1-e^{-bx/c})$?

Comment: @WillR: for the rotated hyperbola perhaps $xy=1$ would be an easier place to start, having an asymptote already in the right direction?

Comment: Along those lines, $c(1-\frac{c}{bx+c})$ would do.

Comment: Or $x \mapsto c \tanh \left(\frac{b x}{c}\right)$.

Comment: $c(1-e^{-bx/c})$ is the closest to what I'm looking for. Ideally I'd like to be able to write it in the form $xg(x)$ where $g(x)$ is from function that forces $x$ to converge to $c$.

Comment: @Drew: $g(x)=\dfrac{c(1-e^{-bx/c})}{x}$? ($g$ has a removable singularity at $0$, so take $g(0)=b$.)

Comment: There are zillion other ways to achieve this, you should give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A physically-grounded expression (such as the charge of a capacitor over time) is $$y=c(1-e^{-bx/c}).$$

Here with $b=2,c=3$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks for all the world, to be an error function. So let's say

$$y=c\ \text{erf}(ax)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=c\frac{2a}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-a^2x^2}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}\big|_{x=0}=c\frac{2a}{\sqrt{\pi}}=b\\
a=\frac{b\sqrt{\pi}}{2c}
$$